# Joomla query select left join with $var

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, left-join

I need to get a left join with a `$var`! Without variable the code works:

```
$query->select('d.value AS department');
$query->join('LEFT', '#__jea_departments AS d ON d.id = p.department_id');
```

I tried all the syntax for entering a variable, but it does not work!

```
$var="d.test";

$query->select('**$test** AS department');
$query->join('LEFT', '#__jea_departments AS d ON d.id = p.department_id');
```

I tried `"$test"  {$test}` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing string literals with single quotes, this is the problem. PHP doesn't interpolate variables within strings defined with single quotes. Change them to double quotes to resolve:

```
$query->select("$test AS department");
```

Alternatively concatenate the variables:

```
$query->select($test . ' AS department');
```

From the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single):

> Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

Comment: The second way is the joomla way but you should be using the quoting api.

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotes. Then it will not transform $test into the propper value. Use double quotes or use $test .' as department'

```
$test = 'd.test';
print '$test as department';  //will print: $test as department
print "$test as department";  //will print: d.test as department
print $test. ' as department';  //will print: d.test as department
```